# Keep cmd open for period of time

Tags: windows, command-line, php

I have scheduled a taks on my windows 7 machine to run every 15 minutes and I have that working.

The command is `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\vmstage.php"`

Still, all working. When running that php script, it returns some text. Is it possible to keep `cmd` open for a few seconds so I can see what the result was?

Right now, the behavior is:

1. `cmd` opens
2. script runs
3. waits for result (2-5 seconds)
4. returns data
5. `cmd` closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `timeout` command that will pause shell for some period of time or until you press a button. You can create a `.cmd` file with a content like that:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\vmstage.php"
timeout 5
```

`.cmd` files are just a lists of commands that are executed top to bottom. This one will execute your task and wait for 5 seconds. Schedule that file's execution instead of your current command.

Comment: is it possible to do the reverse? I want the execution of the php script to happen and then timeout

Comment: nevermind, just tested it and it works. thank you! I'll accept in 5 mins. Won't let me yet

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited the answer to be more clear and correct.